# Including doxygen's LaTeX output as an appendix to a larger document

Tags: latex, doxygen

I have a "project book" which uses LaTeX's `\documentclass{report}` ("report" is like a more compact version of `\documentclass{book}`). I would like to include into this book an appendix with the Doxygen-generated API documentation for the software in the project.

I have achieved this by setting Doxygen's config options `LATEX_HEADER` and `LATEX_FOOTER` to an empty file.  This makes the resulting latex/refman.tex have top level commands like: `\section{\-Namespace \-Index}`, at which point I can wrap this with a top level document like:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{doxygen.sty}
% the "import" package helps to find Doxygen files in the latex/ subdirectory
\usepackage{import}
% [...] title page and the rest of the book

\appendix
\chapter{API reference (generated by Doxygen)
subimport{latex/}{refman.tex}

% [...] final stuff
\end{document}
```

This works reasonably well and I get `doxygen.sty` with this special doxygen invocation:

```
doxygen -w latex /dev/null /dev/null doxygen.sty
```

One problem is that this puts an "autogenerated" header on the entire document (not just on the doxygen appendix).  I can get rid of this by editing `doxygen.sty` (I also rename it for my inclusion, actually) and commenting out the block that starts with `% Setup fancy headings`.

At this point I have something I can live with, but I would like to go one step further: the "doxygen" style modifies a lot of other aspects of the LaTeX document style, and I like it less.

So my question is (in two levels of excellence):

1. What would be a minimal set of LaTeX commands to put in a doxygen.sty file that would nicely render the doxygen appendix but not interfere with the rest of the LaTeX document?
2. Even better, has someone come up with a way of doing

   ```
   \usepackage{doxygen_standalone}
   % [... until you need doxygen]
   \begin{doxygen}
   % the stuff you need to insert your auto-generated doxygen API docs,
   % for example the \subimport{latex/}{refman.tex} that I showed above
   \end{doxygen}
   ```

This last approach is one I would consider very clean.

I'm hoping there is a really simple answer, such as "this already exists in doxygen.sty as an option, and you missed it!"

Comment: I have the same question.  Can anyone comment?  See also my post to [SO here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219578/individual-function-docs-in-latex-using-doxygen).

Comment: I have included Doxygen latex-generated PDF using pdfpages package.

Comment: It doesn't really come close to a proper answer, but one way could be to pinpoint what commands you want to revert and use \renewcommand or \forgetcommand to remove them. I imagine you could probably also use \includeonly to selectively get what you want without the commands.

Answer (score 1):

rename doxygen.sty to mydoxygen.sty, then modify it by inserting
\newenvironment{doxygen}{... most of doxygen.sty goes here ...}{}

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? I'm not sure what's the advantage and how to use it after I wrapped it in the new environment.