# Individual function docs in LaTeX using doxygen

Tags: latex, doxygen

I'm writing a manual of sorts in LaTeX for some software.  I'm constrained to use the *article* class.  I must include docs of individual c++ classes in the manual.  I'm looking at doxygen for this, but I've never used doxygen (if there's a better way, let me know).

I can get doxygen to produce a nice LaTeX (--> pdf) file of my entire project.  But what I'd like to do is somehow extract the LaTeX source for each class and drop it into my LaTeX manual source at the appropriate place.

I've tried putting all the preamble stuff from refman.tex (generated by doxygen) in *my* preamble, and then later in the document using `\input` to include the tex file of an individual class.  After cleaning up a few conflicts, I get to one that I don't know how to get past.  The doxygen-generated doxygen.sty file makes reference to `\chaptermark`, but I believe that this is a macro defined in the *book* class.

So 1.) Am I going about this all the wrong way?  2.)Is it possible to force Doxygen to produce code in the *article* class?  3.) Anything else?

-garyp

Answer (score 2):

You can make doxygen produce a document that uses the *article* document class by setting `COMPACT_LATEX` to `YES` in your doxygen config file.